# Http post method Key significance

Tags: module, http-post, at-command

I am facing a challenge in sending data to http server through AT command

Condition Given:

"The version of HTTP used should be 1.1 or
higher, HTTP key should be 'logdata' and the HTTP POST method should be
used to send data."

I can't understand how to submit the key, every time I get 400 bad request error.

AT+HTTPSET="URL","http://13.229.232.186:80"

Comment: What device are you using? And what version? `+HTTPSET` is not a standard command, so if you could also edit your question linking your reference AT guide it could help

Comment: now it is connected to the server but data is not posting stated wrong format... one thing I want to know about key. as how to use key "logdata" for sending data

Comment: fibocom gsm module